# Waiting for Lean server to start... in vscode

Tags: visual-studio, lean

when I started working on Lean proof assistant on visual studio code, I have followed the instructions on Lean webstie but after all of tips the lean Infoviewer didn't show any thing just "Waiting for Lean server to start..." where is the problem ?

Comment: This is hard to debug. The short answer is "you probably didn't do exactly everything in the right order" :-( You don't say if you're using Lean 3 or Lean 4, you don't say if you made a project or are just opening a file etc etc. Come to the Zulip https://leanprover.zulipchat.com/ because you need interactive help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.